# image-preview.html file in Magento 2 Ui component

Tags: magento, magento2, image-upload, uicomponents

I have noticed image-preview.html resides in (view->adminhtml->web->template) in magento 2 module. But i don't understand the code that are referenced within this html file. Here is the source of the image-preview.html file.
`

```
<div class="file-uploader-preview">
    <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
        <img
                class="preview-image"
                tabindex="0"
                event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                attr="
                src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                alt: $file.name">
    </a>

    <div class="actions">
        <button
                type="button"
                class="action-remove"
                data-role="delete-button"
                attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
            <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
<div class="file-uploader-meta">
    <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text 
      args="$file.previewHeight"/>
</div>
```

`

Can someone explain this code to me, else provide what i need to learn to understand and modify this code in my custom magento 2 module as per my requirement.

Comment: Did you understand this code now?

Comment: Not yet..still don't understand $parent and $file variables and can not able to figure out what those variables are referring.